# Accessing files containing whitespace from a zip Static Resource in Apex

Tags: apex, static-resources, zip

There is a [known issue](https://andyinthecloud.com/2012/11/04/handling-office-files-and-zip-files-in-apex-part-1/) with zip Static Resources that prevents files with whitespace in their names from being extracted (I suppose the Static Resource web service on SFDC cannot handle whitespaces). In light of this, what options do we have to access JSON files (containing whitespace in their names) from a zip Static Resource in Apex?

Visualforce is suffering from the same issue so I cannot use `Page.Name.getContent()`. In Aura the same issue is present (since we'd need to make an explicit GET request to the Static Resource web service). In LWC the `platformResourceLoader` module only offers `loadScript` and `loadStyle`. There' nothing to load a JSON file.

Comment: I think the solution is "don't use whitespace". That's not very fun, though. Have you tried replacing the space with either "+" or "%20"?

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes. Neither has worked (404 error returned). Unfortunately this zip file is coming from an external API and we don't have control over it. For background, the goal is to unzip this file. I tried using Zippex but ran into CPU timeout. Now I'm trying to use the built-in unarchiver in Static Resources to get the job done.

Comment: I think you could download the file to the client via XMLHttpRequest, then unzip via jszip and handle on the client. This would work in Visualforce, Aura, and LWC.

Comment: @sfdcfox Using jszip was actually my last option. I wanted to be sure it was not possible to do it without resorting to an external lib. But now that you've said it I'm going to try it out with jszip.

Comment: What if you used Zippex, but did it asynchronously in a Queueable? The class could fire off a Platform Event when the results are ready. Or, I guess if you were really in a bind, a quick Heroku App could do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: @sfdcfox In my approach with Zippex I used async processing. But the zip file was large and it took 60+ secs. Agree about the option of taking the work off of the platform but as we're building an app (product) I want to avoid putting another SPOF on the critical path.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you're stuck with client-side processing. That's a bummer, but at least there's a potential solution.

Comment: @sfdcfox Actually I just realized that this route might be a dead-end since JS in VF won't run when we call `getContent()` in Apex..

Comment: Yes, that's right. You'd have to unzip it then send it to the server, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to rename the files, replacing spaces with %20. So if the static resource was:

```
"images.zip/large image.png"
```

it became

```
"images.zip/large%20image.png"
```

Comment: I'm afraid that if the author had had the option to rename files, he would have just removed whitespaces (@discussion in comments)